# How can i achieve mousemove event on edges on arborjs

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, cytoscape.js, arbor.js

I need to bring the name of the target node, while hovering over the edges for a particular node connected with the edge. Like in this example http://assembl.coeus.ca/static/js/bower/cytoscape/debug/
It uses cytoscape with arborjs. We can customize it from the drop downs to show what I need exactly.

Comment: @rhinds I hope you can answer my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cy.on()` with a delegate selector: http://cytoscape.github.io/cytoscape.js/#core/events/cy.on

Comment: yeah.. i did that...worked successfully. But isn't there a workaround to do it without cytoscape

Comment: Arbor is just a layout algorithm, not a graph library.  If you want to just use Arbor, you'll have to build your own model/event system on top of it.

Comment: thanx for the reply. Can you push me in a right direction so as to achieve my goal. I'll really appreciate it.

Comment: i think i can achieve that, but with cytoscape the fluidity of arborjs layout is lost. Is this also due to the same reason?